# How use a collection only in localStorage with Backbone Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm making a website with Backbone and Marionette and in this website I'm making a shopping cart.

But, in the cart, I don't want to create an endpoint to save the items if the user is unlogged. I want to save only in localStorage.

I'm trying to make this with Backbone.localStorage but I cannot make this.

```
App.Collections.Cart = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: GroovecollabWebsite.Models.Category,
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("localCart")
});
```

I want to make this:

```
var collection = new App.Collections.Cart();
collection.add({/* My model here */}); // Run event to sync with localStorage
collection.remove(<id>); // Run event to sync with localStorage
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save your collection on changes, you can add it in the initializer in your collection:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.on('add remove', function() {
    this.sync();
  });
}
```